# Prevent collapse from collapsing on modal opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open and close a modal without triggering the collapse click event, but since the modal button it's a child of the collapse click element, i can't figure it out a way to do it.

e.stopPropagation() works, but it causes other problems, so it's not an option.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1fr2vx9/)

```css
.wrap {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.well {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Modal
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below `jquery` to prevent collapse from collapsing

```js
$('.modalclk').click(function(){
  $('.wrap').attr('data-toggle','');
});
$(".close, button[data-dismiss='modal']").click(function(){
  $('.wrap').attr('data-toggle','collapse');
});
$('body').on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('modal')) {
    $('.wrap').attr('data-toggle','collapse');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.well {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modalclk" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Modal
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```